# How and where to access a saved text file on Android Adobe Air application

Tags: android, file, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to save a text file from my Android air application but the file is not showing in device filesystem. I'm using the below code to define the save path:

```
var f:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('example' + example_count +'.txt');
```

The file should save to the sd card root but its not showing up. Is there a reason for this behaviour? Any help in resolving this issue would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the right permissions when you publish your app. For saving files you need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. If you are using Flash Professional to develop you can do this in publish settings.

For more information see:

http://richard-heck.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/how-to-write-file-to-android-filesystem.html